Hermitian duals of induced modules
Let $A$ be an associative $\mathbb{C}$-algebra with conjugate-linear anti-automorphism $*$.
For an $A$-module $V$ we define the Hermitian dual $V^\dagger$ as the space of conjugate-linear functionals $V \to \mathbb{C}$ with $A$-module structure
$$(a \cdot \lambda ) (v) =  \lambda (a^{*} \cdot v).$$
Let $B$ be a $*$-subalgebra of $A$. Let $V$ be a finite dimensional irreducible $B$-module with Hermitian dual $V^\dagger$, and suppose that both $V$ and $V^\dagger$ are direct summands of the regular $B$-module $B$. We therefore get that the induced $A$-module $A \otimes_B V$ is a direct summand of the regular $A$-module $A = A \otimes_B B$ and also  $A^\dagger \otimes_B V^\dagger$ is a direct summand of the $A$-module $A^\dagger = A^\dagger \otimes_B B$, by additivity of $\otimes$.
So we have $A \otimes V$ is a direct summand of $A$ and $A^\dagger \otimes V^\dagger$ is a direct summand of $A^\dagger$, both as left $A$-modules.
Does it follow that $(A \otimes V)^\dagger = A^\dagger \otimes V^\dagger$?
